# Configuring VC++ for WxWidgets

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide#Creating_a_new_project_by_hand)
 to configure VC++ for WxWidgets. I got stuck here.
[image: stuck]

So for `Core wxWidgets libraries to include`, I did include `wxmsw31u[d]_core.lib` and `wxbase31u[d].lib` under Linker>>Input>>Additional Depenedencies.  That is all to it right?

As for `Linking with correct runtime library`, can someone tell me how that is done?  I manage to get here but don't know how to set the indicated settings.

[image: lib]

Please help.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to debug your app the debugger must know where in the compiled code is each function used. In jargon, the "debugging symbols". Windows puts these symbols in the compiled executable, while Linux uses another, `.dev`file.

When you compile code (your app or wxWidgets library) you must tell the compiler whether you want a "Debug" version or a "Release" one.

If you want the debugger to be able to step into wxWidgets code, then you must compile wxWidgets in "debug" mode, which will add the character `d` to the library files built. So, you must add, for example, `wxmsw31ud_core.lib` to your app dependencies. Notice the `d` between `u` and `_`. Use the file explorer to see all files generated by wxWidgets compilation process.

Perhaps you don't want all this wxWidgets "debug". Then use another wxWidgets compilation route and add `wxmsw31u_core.lib` instead of the `d`'d version. Still you can compile your own app in debug mode, but not being able to step through wxWidgets internals.

Now for your app, a) do you want a single executable file also containing wxWidgets code? or b) let your app in a `.exe` file which uses as needed external `.dll` files?

a) is called "static linkage" while b) is called "dynamic linkage"

As you can see, there are four combinations of debug/release & static/dynamic. You must choose one "runtime library" to link to your app.

The table in the wiki shows the switch and MSVC lib (select the desired combination in the 'properties' page) to use in your app; and macro definition required to build wxWidgets if you use `nmake` instead of the already provided configurations in VS.

Take a look at *docs\msw\install.txt* for more info.

The best advice I give is that you look into "minimal" sample project. Load it into VS and read every option. You can even make a copy, change some file names and use it for your own app.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [official instructions](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.1/docs/msw/install.txt#L491) instead of the wiki, they're simpler and, if you look at the last paragraph, you can see that you don't even have to link the libraries manually with MSVC.

You also don't need to do anything special to link with the correct version of the CRT, the defaults are just fine.

Comment: Thanks!!!  I didnt know that Wiki page was NOT the official document for WxWidgets.